# incompatible pointer types assigning to 'nsmutablearray ' from 'nsarray '

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, nsarray

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"self" ascending:YES];

sortedFloats = [Arr_distance sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:
                    [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];
```

where `sortedFloats` is NSMutableArray and `Arr_distance` is also NSMutableArray

I got the warning `Incompatible pointer types assigning to 'NSMutableArray ' from 'NSArray '`  still result is correct, but whats the warning about?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take your `sortedFloats` as **NSArray** instead of **NSMutableArray**. You will find your warning disappeared.

Enjoy Programming

Answer (score 2):

There is two issues in that code:

1. Parameter type of `sortedArrayUsingDescriptors` is `NSArray` you are passing an `NSMutableArray`
2. Return type of `sortedArrayUsingDescriptors` is `NSArray` you are assigning it to `NSMutableArray` object

Check the method signature:

```
- (NSArray *)sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:(NSArray *)sortDescriptors
```

Answer (score 0):

In `sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:` you default object you should pass is `NSArray`.You are getting the warning as you are passing `NSMutableArray`.

According to the documentation:

```
- (NSArray *)sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:(NSArray *)sortDescriptors
```

Answer (score 0):

Here `sortedFloats` is object of `NSMutableArray` and also you sort the array using array key with `sortedArrayUsingDescriptors` method of `NSMutableArray` which return `NSArray`..

so here this `sortedArrayUsingDescriptors` method's returns type is `NSArray` and you store this return type array in object of `NSMutableArray` name is `sortedFloats` so take `sortedFloats` as a object of `NSArray` class.
i hope this help you...